# timepicker as constant when the time picker is started in blackberry

Tags: blackberry

here i am using the blackberry 8520 to display the timepicker. i want to set the time as 10:00:00 upto when the timepickerstarts to change the time in the simuator

```
         public void run()
          {
            //create timepicker by using this method
            //by using this simpledateformat we set time format 
             SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss aa"); 
            DateTimePicker datepicker = DateTimePicker.createInstance(Calendar.getInstance(),null,"hh:mm:ss aa");
             datepicker.doModal();          
            StringBuffer datestrTime=new StringBuffer();
            //by using this method we get date from system date&time
            Calendar cal = datepicker.getDateTime();       


            timeFormat.format(cal,datestrTime, null);

            // we are taking the current time from the system and displaying in the label field 
           time_picker.setText(datestrTime.toString());

          }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the below code:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR,10);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,00);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND,00);

datepicker.setDateTime(cal);
datepicker.doModal();
```